# Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of '[(super or self) init...]'

Tags: xcode, instance

```
- (id)init{
    if(![super init]){
        return nil;
    }
    _rssItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    return self;
}
```

If I analyze my project I get this warning:

> Instance variable used while 'self' is not set to the result of
>   '[(super or self) init...]'

What do I have to change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nowadays, Apple's official recommendation is:

```
- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _rssItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The idea is that `init` (in particular, in this case, `[super init]`) is allowed to return an object other than self, and the expected behavior in that case is to work with that object instead--the easiest way to deal with this is to just set `self` to whatever `super` returns. Also note that `return self;` works fine whether `self` is nil or not, hence the reversal of your `if`.

Of course, *most* classes don't perform this switching trick--but this is good practice anyway because Apple expects everyone to be using this exact pattern for their `init`, so even if your subclass currently works without assigning to `self`, they could easily change that behavior in the future without warning.

Comment: Thank you but now I my app crashes because an EXC_BAD_ACCESS... Strange because the previous Issue disappeared.